# How remove duplicate row and cont that value?

Tags: php

[image]In case of two same names, one name gets removed but the number will be incremented to show the total count as two. write php script

Comment: We are going to need a lot more information than that to be able to answer this.

Comment: @SkandarajahShyamalan could you please mark the best answer as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are using php and database.

`$oneDataFromdatabase = SELECT * from table_name where name = $name`

use select where query and get value then

```
$data = $oneDataFromdatabase;

$value = $data['value']; 

$finalValue = $value + 1;


// update query for update value


UPDATE tabel_name SET value = $value WHERE name = $name
```

Comment: @SkandarajahShyamalan where is you'r data located ?

Comment: data loading database but can't change database records